# SQL Query: Where, Like, OR - Combing these

Tags: php, sql

In my database I have a table named 'model'. Here is how most of these look like:

```
iphone 4 16gb white t-mobile
```

and another:

```
iphone 4 32gb black kpn
```

Now I want to select with a query those different iPhones.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND '%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I want my query to look for "iphone 4" and then look for "16gb". So it only outputs iPhone 4's with 16GB. The query above is not working. Is it my syntax? Or is it not possible like this?

Comment: what is the resultset you're getting? or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16gb%'
```

You can't have the following expression in SQL:

```
model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND '%16gb%'
```

You need to state both expressions completely:

```
model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16gb%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query from:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND '%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there but you need to explicitly state the comparison on the 16gb

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model Like'%16gb%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's syntax

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

OR note this doesn't take into account ORDER where as the above does.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND  model like '%16gb%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need a sub-query, i.e.

```
select * 
from (select * from db where model LIKE '%iphone 4%') xx
where xx.model like '%16gb%'
```

The inner query builds a set of all iphone 4 models, and the outer query gets those with 16gb..